# Are questions about 3d printer reccomendations on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions

Many people find it's hard to get a good guide for 3d printing.  Is a question about what printer a beginner should get on topic?

Comment: On-topic on http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kenorb And why does the scope of another site matter here?

Comment: @Zizouz212 It matters, because we can redirect person who has the question to the right place within the same network.